# Using Spinner in ArayAdapter getting null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-adapter

I'm having problem in displaying my Spinner in ArrayAdapter.It's getting null I don't know why.The error is Null Pointer Exception.Please help me out of this. Here's my code.

```
package com.example.senditem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.functions.ClientModel;
import com.functions.JSONParser;
import com.functions.Model;
import com.functions.MyAdapter;
import com.functions.SqliteHelper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UserProductActivity extends Activity {
 ListView listView;
    Button btnSend;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnSearch;
    Button btnUpload;
    Spinner inputUom;
    String items;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter;
    List<String> uomlist;
    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
    ArrayList<ClientModel> sales = new ArrayList<ClientModel>();
    private String search_product;
    private String phoneNo;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private static String upload = "http://192.168.0.101/MyAndroidConnect/upload.php";
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_ITEM = "items";
    private static String KEY_AGENT = "agent";
    private static String KEY_DAYS = "days";
    private static String KEY_BARCODE = "barcode";
    private static String KEY_CLIENT = "client";
    private static String KEY_QTY = "qty";
    private static String KEY_UOM = "uom";

    String acode;
    String days;
    String client;
    String bcode;
    String qty;
    String uom;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.userprodmain);
        Intent i=getIntent();
        final Bundle b = i.getExtras();
        final SqliteHelper db = new SqliteHelper(this);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
//      btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
        inputUom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.inputUom);


        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, getModel(), Integer.parseInt(b.get("id").toString()) );
//      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),b.get("id").toString(),       
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        final List<String> uomlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int j=0;j<list.size();j++){
            String barcode = list.get(j).getBar();
            uomlist.add(db.selectUom(barcode));



   //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),db.selectUom(barcode),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }




 ArrayAdapter<String> uomadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,uomlist);
        uomadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        inputUom.setAdapter(uomadapter);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final View v) {
                    listView.clearFocus();
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                    alert.setTitle("Save Details?");
                    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            if(list.get(i).getQuantity()!=null)
                            {
//  Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), String.valueOf(list.get(i).getprodId()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    db.addItem(new Model(Integer.parseInt(b.get("id").toString()), list.get(i).getprodId(), list.get(i).getQuantity(),list.get(i).getAmt()));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        });
                    alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             dialog.cancel();
                         }
                     });
                    alert.show();
            }
         });



        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(final View v) {
                     AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                     alert.setTitle("Search Item");
                     final EditText input = new EditText(v.getContext());
                     input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                     alert.setView(input);
                     alert.setPositiveButton("Search", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                             search_product = input.getText().toString();
                             int z=0;
                             for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                                 if(search_product.toUpperCase().equals(list.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())){
                                     listView.setSelection(i);
                                     z=0;
                                 }
                                 else
                                     z++;
                             }
                             if(z==list.size())
                             {
                               AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext()).create();
                               alert.setTitle("No Data Found!");
                               alert.show();
                             }
                         }
                     });
                     alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             dialog.cancel();
                         }
                     });


                 alert.setMessage("Input Message");
  //          alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
  //          alert.setCancelMessage(null);
                     alert.show();
            }
        });



btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(final View v) {

                new UploadSales().execute();
            }





  });

    }
     private List<Model> getModel() {
        Intent i=getIntent();
        final Bundle b = i.getExtras();
        SqliteHelper db = new SqliteHelper(this);
        list = db.getAllProduct(b.get("clientCode").toString(),b.get("day").toString());
        return list;
    }

  class UploadSales extends AsyncTask <String,String,String>{

      @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Uploading Sales. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }


      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {

                        Intent i=getIntent();
                        final Bundle b = i.getExtras();
                        SqliteHelper db = new SqliteHelper(getApplicationContext()); 


                        for(int j=0; j<list.size(); j++){

                            acode = db.getAgent(1);
                            days = b.get("day").toString();
                            client = b.get("clientCode").toString();
                            bcode = list.get(j).getBar();
                            qty = list.get(j).getQuantity();
                            uom = list.get(j).getUom();         



                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("agent", acode));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("days", days));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("barcode", bcode));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client", client));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uom", uom));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty", qty));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                upload, "POST", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(KEY_SUCCESS);

                        if (success == 1) {
                           //


                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }








  }
```

}

what's the problem here?

**LOGCAT**

```
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.senditem/com.example.senditem.UserProductActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5400)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at com.example.senditem.UserProductActivity.onCreate(UserProductActivity.java:104)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2336)
08-04 11:44:12.812: E/AndroidRuntime(28977):    ... 11 more
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_width="90dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@+id/label"
android:textSize="15sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/inputAmt"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputQty"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="12sp" >



 <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/inputUom"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you initialized inputUom?

Comment: yes i already have initialized inputUom as Spinner

Comment: Post your LogCat please.

Comment: where is the cause of NPE.could you post the full source code and the logcat.

Comment: i have posted my logcat. i think the cause of NPE is when i'm trying to place uomlist in arrayAdapter

Comment: full source code please

Comment: here's my full source code

Comment: Should i need to post my xml?

Comment: please help me with this.I really need help i need to finish it today

Comment: @user3339568 you got Error At this line? ` ArrayAdapter<String> uomadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,uomlist);`

Comment: I was mistaken. the cause of error is in this line inputUom.setAdapter(uomadapter);

Answer (score 0):

see here is your mistake :

replace

```
 adapter = new MyAdapter(this, getModel(), Integer.parseInt(b.get("id").toString()) );
//      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),b.get("id").toString(),       
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

with

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(this, getModel(), Integer.parseInt(b.get("id").toString()) );
//      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),b.get("id").toString(),       
//               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and one more mistake i found check uomlist you declare it twice in your code one globally and second locally so just remove locally declaration
Replace

```
final List<String> uomlist=new ArrayList<String>()
```

to just

```
uomlist=new ArrayList<String>()
```

thats it...

Comment: I tried it but still didn't work :( when i tried to comment my code line by line i found out that the cause of error here is in this line >> inputUom.setAdapter(uomadapter);

Comment: your main problem is second issue i declared above try this just remove final List<String> in onCreate... it fixed your issue

Comment: no there are no any problem in your xml here just concept issue you put your all data in local uomlist and in adapter bind global uomlist list which is not initialized so it gives you NPE error. thats it...

Comment: so what should i do next? i already remove the final List<String> in my local declaration but didn't work.

Comment: clean and build your project.

Comment: Will cleaning the project not affect R.? Sometimes cleaning the project R. gets error.

Comment: one more thing i dont understand where you fill "list<model>" arraylist if it fill in doinback then when you call it. and one more thing just create one local arraylist and fill data locally to it and pass it to your adapter and check error is occur or not.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-spinner-dropdown-example/ check this link here static data added to list and display in spinner.